# Error handling using poller

Tags: error-handling, spring-integration

I'm trying to handle errors using a the int:poller without success. I defined an error-channel on the poller but when an error occurs, nothing goes to that channel. Here's my code. Any ideas?

```
<int:channel id="auditRequestMessagesChannel">
    <int:queue />
</int:channel>
<int:service-activator id="auditRequestMessages" input-channel="auditRequestMessagesChannel" ref="auditTaskBean" method="registerEvent" >
    <int:poller fixed-rate="1000" error-channel="auditErrorChannel" />
</int:service-activator>
<int:channel id="auditErrorChannel" />
<int:logging-channel-adapter id="auditErrorChannelLogger" channel="auditErrorChannel" expression="'[Audit] '+#this"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Turn on DEBUG logging and take a look at the log; if it's still not clear what's happening, post the log someplace.

Comment: Gary, I made some basic tests and found that the errorChannel is not correctly set by the poller. I used a header-enricher (setting the errorChannel) before the service-activator and worked fine. Could be something with the poller?

Comment: I just ran a test and it works exactly as expected for me; what version of Spring Integration are you using? You should not have to manipulate the headers yourself; adding the `error-channel` to the poller is the correct way.